Extract data from DB or populate it with fixtures before running tests
My pytest runs do not extract the db in the real database which I believe is normal as test DB is initially empty.
Part of my code requires that I fetch the id of a page in an existing model.
def result_page_get_id_from_slug(slug):
    print(ContentPage.objects.values().last())
    obj = ContentPage.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return obj.id

There's no way I can do this in tests sice test db is empty. So I keep gettign the following error:
home.models.ContentPage.DoesNotExist: ContentPage matching query does not exist.

When I try to print all objects during testing I get None meaning that ContentPage model is empty during test run.
 print(ContentPage.objects.values().last())

How can I populate it please. Thanks
